# JavaFX - How to get AnchorPane inside a GridPane and add Text on it?

Tags: javafx, gridpane

I know I can add `Text` or `Node` inside `GridPane` with the Following code

```
Text text = new Text("Hello World");
gridPane.add(text, row, column);
```

But I have `AnchorPane` inside every `rows` and `columns` of `GridPane` which is manually inserted by the help of `SceneBuilder`, inside the `AnchorPane` I want to add the `Text`. Something like getting the children of `GridPane` and add the `Text` on it.

I do it like this but it doesn't work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < column; j++){
     Text text = new Text("Hello World!");
     gridPane.getChildren().add(text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < column; j++){
     Text text = new Text("Hello World!");

    for(Node node : gridPane.getChildren()){
        Integer r = gridPane.getRowIndex(node);
        Integer c = gridPane.getColumnIndex(node);
        if(r!=null && r.intValue() == row && c != null && c.intValue() == column){
            AnchorPane anchorPane = (AnchorPane)node;
            anchorPane.getChildren().add(txt);
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty close... but the first `Column` and last `Row` has no `Text`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 gridPane.getChildren().add(text);
```

adds `text` to the `GridPane` at row 0, column 0, i.e. it has the same effect as

```
 gridPane.add(text, 0, 0);
```

(Actually this is not 100% the same, but the difference is unimportant in this context.)

Assuming every child of the `GridPane` is a `AnchorPane`, you need to retrieve every child, cast it to `Pane` and add the `Text` to it's child list:

```
for (Node child : gridPane.getChildren()) {
    Pane pane = (Pane) child;
    Text text = new Text("Hello World!");
    pane.getChildren().add(text);
}
```

Of course you could use different approaches for retrieving elements from a list instead of the enhances for loop. The order of the children in the list matches the order of the elements in the `<children>` element of the `<GridPane>` element in the fxml file. (This is the order they appear in in the hierarchy view of SceneBuilder.)

Comment: I'm using `AnchorPane` not `Pane` and the result is same as what I'm having right now. It's like a special character in random place of `GridPane`.

Comment: @KrixMuxDeadpool `Pane` is the supertype of `AnchorPane` where `getChildren`is made`public`. Using `Pane` or `AnchorPane` does not make a difference as long as every child of the GridPane is a AnchorPane. The code above does exactly what you wanted as long as there are only anchorpanes in the grid.I cannot help you with the other issue, since you haven't posted any details about the children of the `GridPane` and the time when your method is invoked. I assume you'd be better of creating both the `AnchorPane`s and the `Text` elements they are supposed to contain to the `gridPane` via your loop.